# Sum of Value by Category and Status Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am Attempting to get a sum of ppl that is based on the status of the offer
here is an example of the data

| Acc | PPL | Offer comp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDE | 1 | 1 |
| ABCDE | 1 | 0 |
| ABCDE | 1 | 0 |
| CDEFG | 2 | 0 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 1 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 0 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 0 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 1 |
| EFGHI | 2 | 1 |
| EFGHI | 2 | 1 |
| EFGHI | 2 | 0 |

And this is what I am wanting to achieve as a column either in Power query or Dax

| Account | PPL | Offer Comp | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDE | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ABCDE | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| ABCDE | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| ABCDE | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| BCDEF | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| BCDEF | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| CDEFG | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| DEFGH | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| EFGHI | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| EFGHI | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| EFGHI | 2 | 0 | 4 |

Basically, we are looking for a count of ppl where if the offer is not completed, we count the ppl, if the offer is accepted, we count the ppl for each acceptance.

Hope this makes sense I would then use this column to create measures as they want ppl count to be unique unless they accepted multiple offers on same account.

I tried to create with selected values and all except but I just couldn't get it to work.
I am probably completely overthinking this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrive at your expected results. Could you clarify a few of them?

Comment: Some comment. Provide detail based on your sample what the output is checking or counting

Comment: Hello, business wants a count of unique count of ppl where offers are made... unless they have accessed multiple offers. then they want them to be count for each offer.

Comment: It would be sum of offers * max # of ppl by account, unless offers = 0 then it would be max ppl by account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out with help from Marcus

thank you. I realised also need to add a date grouping.

here is the code

```
   Total = 
   VAR _offer = 
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Offer Comp]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table [Account], Table[Date]))

   VAR Pax = 
    CALCULATE(MAX(Table[PPL]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Account]))

   RETURN
    IF(_offer = 0, 
        Pax *1,
            pax*_offer
   )
```

Comment: I would generally advise you to provide better sample data next time you ask a question - there is no `Date` anywhere in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Very cryptic, and I must admit the sample data and your description is not great, but I think you are after something like this:

```
Total = 
VAR _offer = 
    SUMX ( 
        ALLEXCEPT (
            'Table' , 
            'Table'[Account]
        ) , 
        'Table'[Offer Comp] * 'Table'[PPL]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 
        _offer > 0 , 
        _offer ,
        CALCULATE ( 
            MAX ( 'Table'[PPL] ) ,
            ALLEXCEPT ( 
                'Table' , 
                'Table'[Account] 
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: This is definitely along the lines I am looking for, thank you.
however, I am getting a circular reference error when I try and run.